# Operator -> doesn't work as expected in C++

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I was practicing single linked list in c++ (practicing how to find the beginning node of the circular list), but found the use of **operator ->** very confusing. I'm using Visual studio 2010 C++ Express

This works perfectly: `head->append(2)->append(3)->append(4)->append(5)`

But this doesn't work (to create a circular linked list): `head->append(2)->append(3)->append(4)->append(5)->append(head->next)`

When I jump in this method and debug, it seems `head->next` is not passed correctly into the method.

But this works:

1. `Node* tail=head->append(2)->append(3)->append(4)->append(5);
   tail->append(head->next);`
2. Or after I change `return c->next` to `return head` in the two methods, `head->append(2)->append(3)->append(4)->append(5)->append(head->next)`  also works.

What am I missing here? Thank you!

Details of my code is as follows:

```
void main(){
    Node* head=new Node(1);
    Node* tail=head->append(2)->append(3)->append(4)->append(5)->append(head->next);
    cin.get();
}

class Node{
public:
    Node* next;
    int data;
    bool marked;

    Node(int d){
        data=d;
        marked=false;
        next=NULL;
    }

    Node* append(int d){
        Node* c=this;
        while(c->next!=NULL){
            c=c->next;
        }
        c->next=new Node(d);
        return c->next;
    }

    Node* append(Node* n){
        Node* c=this;
        while(c->next!=NULL){
            c=c->next;
        }
        c->next=n;
        return c->next;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is that a new record for indirection chaining?

Comment: @Mysticial - I think I used a longer chain in a project once, but I've lost track of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are experiencing **undefined behavior**.

The problem is that you are expecting `head->next` to be evaluated at a particular time (right before calling the last `append()`.  But that is not guaranteed.

Comment: So it's not defined in c++ standard, and every compiler can interpret it in their own ways?

Comment: That is correct.  When the order of evaluation is important to you (as it is here), separate those calls.

Answer (score 2):

When you're passing `head->next` - its before changing it with `head->append`. I'm afraid you're confusing the order of writing with the order of execution.

In this case you're changing the value and reading it in the same execution statement, that's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`head->next` is evaluated first. The compiler is at liberty to do so; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713892/when-are-parameters-calculated-when-having-concatenated-call-obj-f1-f2-f3).

Answer (score 0):

head->next is NULL (doesn't point to anything) at the time that statement is evaluated.

Comment: Maybe not, but very likely. We'd have to examine what the compiler outputs to know for sure, but it's most likely it uses the value of head->next at the beginning of the evaluation of the whole statement. The constructor sets next to NULL.