# C++ How cout is excuted in this program?

Tags: c++

How the tryout.main() cout is executed first and then prints main() function cout and finally printing the return value of tryout.main(). This is bit confusing. can any one explain it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class TryOut
{
public:
 int main()
 {
    std::cout<<"In TryOut Main Function "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
TryOut tryout;
std::cout<<"In Main function: "<<tryout.main()<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
In TryOut Main Function 
In Main function: 0
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Borgleader they are probably expecting a different ordering.

Comment: This is, in essence, the same question as [When are parameters calculated, when having concatenated call: obj.F1().F2().F3( sin(x) )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713892/when-are-parameters-calculated-when-having-concatenated-call-obj-f1-f2-f3/4714440#4714440).

Comment: Two main functions?? :O

Comment: This will get closed soon, so I'll just say that the order of `std::cout::operator<<` is well defined (it'd be weird if it wasn't) however the order of function calls isn't (in this case, `std::cout::operator<<` vs `tryout.main()`). This sounds in weird in typing, so I hope you understand where I'm getting at.

Comment: @Rapptz Yes. And in fact, the duplicate I had suggested is not really a duplicate because of this. The problem here is not due to the order of the evaluations of the arguments not being specified. I'll vote to reopen. Perhaps somebody else finds a better duplicate (if there is one).

Comment: This person [posted this identical code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17391294/445976) as an _answer_ over three weeks ago. I don't know why they posted it as a _question_ today.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Well, it's an answer to a completely different question...

Comment: @jogojapan: It's just odd to post code as an answer that when the poster has no idea what it does.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I don't think so. The idea there was to give an example of a program with two `main()` in them. It didn't matter what exactly those functions do.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Sorry i have deleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an edited answer. I was proven wrong by Igor Tandetnik, and since my answer was (incorrectly) accepted and highest voted, I decided to rewrite it to make it correct.

In our case

`foo() = ostream& ostream::operator<<(const char*)`

The order of execution in a sequence of:

`obj.foo("str").foo(fun())`

may be either:

```
obj.foo("str");
fun();
obj.foo(fun_res);
```

or

```
fun();
obj.foo("str");
obj.foo(fun_res);
```

In your case the latter happened, but the former is also a valid execution order.

The order guarantees are as follows:

- `fun()` will happen before `obj.foo(fun_res)`, because the result of foo is required for that call,
- `obj.foo("str")` will happen before `obj.foo(fun_res)`.

Hence the abovementioned two cases are possible.

Comment: `In Main function: In TryOut Main Function 0` could legally be produced, too. It's one possible order of execution.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No it couldn't, for the same reason why the question is not a duplicate (although it was me who suggested this first). Dariusz is right that, while the order of evaluations of arguments amongst themselves is unspecified, all arguments must be evaluated before the actual function call is performed.

Comment: But cout will execute from right to left. Now that is contradicting.

Comment: @jogojapan: yes it could. The expression is parsed as `(cout.operator>>("In TryOut Main Function ")).operator>>(tryout.main())`, or schematically, `(cout.op("s")).op(f())`. Now, in a member function call like `expr.method(arg1, arg2)`, not only is the order of evaluation of `arg1` and `arg2` unspecified, but also the order of evaluation of `expr`. All you can say is that actual `method()` call will happen after all three are evaluated. Applying this to the example at hand, `cout.op("s")` could run before or after `f()` - all you know is that `op(result-of-f())` will happen last.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, you are right after all. I have upvoted your answer, but I really think you should explain it in detail there.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK, I thought about your comment and edited my answer. Thanks, I learned something today!

Answer (score 2):

The order of evaluation of subexpressions within an expression is, in general, unspecified. `tryout.main()` may be legally called before or after `std::cout<<"In Main function: "` is executed. In your case, it happens to be called before.

Answer (score 0):

"<<" in C++ is actually syntactic sugar, when you do

```
cout << "Hello"
```

you're actually calling either

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const char*)
```

or

ostream& ostream::operator<<(const char*)

For convenience, I'm going to assume the latter. When you write

```
std::cout<<"In Main function: "<<tryout.main()<<std::endl;
```

this would compile to

```
cout.operator<<("In Main function: ").operator<<(tryout.main()).operator<<(std::endl);
```

So the code you wrote as

```
<<tryout.main()<<
```

says: "call tryout.main(), capture the return value, and pass that to "ostream::operator<<(int)", using the ostream returned by the previous <<.

So - now tryout.main() is called and executed, which does it's own output, quite independently, and then returns 0.

Now your main function is able to finish it's call chain with the return value of 0 as an argument.

Was there a reason you were not able to step through this with a debugger?

Comment: Yeah. From primer i got to know cout will execute from right to left. but here its quite different. so it is still executed from right to left?

Comment: "cout" doesn't execute, it's an object. You mean "<<", and to answer your question, http://ideone.com/mLmT10, or step thru with a debugger -- in Visual Studio using F11 to "step into" each function call as you go, or in gdb use "s" instead of "n".